# PrettyFaces redirect doesn't work

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I'm trying to set view page for particular URL, but it doesn't work, here is a code:

pretty-config.xml:

```
<pretty-config>

<url-mapping id="loginPage">
    <pattern value="/app"></pattern>
    <view-id>/loginPage.xhtml</view-id>
</url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>FiranyCRM</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

If I set url in browser like this: `FiranyCRM/loginPage.xhtml` then view will load, but when I change loginPage.xhtml into /app then it doesn't work and error appears on browser "Not found", console in eclipse doesn't say anything about it

Comment: Have you followed all [the steps](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) for the set up?

Comment: What version of PrettyFaces are you using?